# How can I fix this program that accepts passwords with partial matching

Tags: python

I'm creating a Login & Password program in Python for my school, I've created already the sign up part with many validations and it fully works & the login part partly works.

The login part has a issue. It locates the username and also the password however it also locates the password beginning  with that initial and it lets you log in the account (bug). For example, my password is "mat" if I type ma or m it will let me log into the account. But the good thing is it doesn't let me log in with other letters just those.

```
PATH=("pass"+" "+username+".txt")

if os.path.isfile(PATH) and os.access(PATH, os.R_OK):
    print ("Username does exist please enter password: ")
    w = input("Password:  ") 
    with open("pass"+" "+username+".txt") as f:
        found = False
        for line in f:
            if w in line:
                loginuser()
                found = True
        if not found:
            print("Wrong password. Please re-enter")
            login()
else:
    print("Username not found.")
```

Comment: Maybe for line in f: is doing characters?  have you tried printing out what line is and what f is to debug what the loop is doing...?

Comment: It seems as if you are storing passwords in plaintext. That is a really bad idea. Please don't do this!

Comment: I assumed that the for is doing for each line in the text file and there is only 1 password in the text file. It works the program fully however if I type a initial beginning with that password it lets me log in ? very weird.

Comment: Does it let you in with just `t`?

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer It's not for anyone just for my personal testing.

Comment: @melpomene If the password is like tomato (for example) it will let me in with t.

Comment: @ToxicPreys Wrong. Did you try it with your original `mat` password?

Comment: @ToxicPreys: *"I assumed that..."* - The important lesson here isn't how to correct this particular piece of code.  The important lesson here is to *never assume*.  Always test and validate.

Comment: Thanks @David yeah I fixed it , i'm only 14 I can code some javascripts and I can do a lot of Python.

Comment: @melpomene yeah I fixed it using line.strip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line, which check for substring match

```
if w in line:
```

With complete string match

```
if w == line.strip():
```

Your string ends with '\n' that's why you need to trim it. This would also delete spaces at string beginning and end, like " mat   \n" would become "mat", so be careful.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using this line

```
if w in line:
```

You are checking if a part of that line contains the input so the below are correct:

```
"w" in "password" -> True
"pass" in "password" -> True
"word" in "password" -> True
```

and this is of course not correct, you need to check for equality thus:

```
if w == line.strip():
```

should do the job

Comment: ty mate i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
if w in line:
```

tests if any letter of the input 'w' is in the line of the password text file. You need to do an equivalence test like so:

```
if line == w:
```

so that an exact match logs the user in, and not just if one or more letters match.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the passwords each on a separate line why don't you just directly compare them. So instead of doing if w in line do this instead:
if w==line